# Rails, Globalize 3 and CRUD operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, localization, models

How am I supposed to write the forms for my models where I'm using globalize3 for translations. I cannot find any examples and I don't find any helpers in the code.
The idea would be to have everything in one form like

text_field :title

text_field :title_fr

text_field :title_en

etc....

Thanks for pointing me to some code examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like everything I need is in batch_translations fork adapted to Rails3/Globalize3:

https://github.com/fidel/batch_translations

I don't know if I supposed to delete this question or leave it for the future. Moderators please decide :)